# Options to storing data in a prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

After realizing that you can't really use `UnityEvents` in Scriptable Objects (they don't read global variable values correctly). I had to move to another solution for where to store my Dialogs.

The best solution I could find was to just store them in the corresponding NPC-prefab. This is really convenient. However this leaves a bad taste in my mouth, it just feels wrong to store data in a prefab like this. Is it a bad practice? 
For example if I were to refactor something in the `DialogObject`, everything would be lost.

Since I can't seem to successfully store UnityEvents anywhere (can't serialize them as Json and as mentioned Scriptable Objects don't seem to handle them well) I feel like this is the only solution if I want to be able to use the Editor to create Dialogs.

Just checking here first, is this stupid? is there another way?

I am trying to save a `List` of this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DialogObject {
    public List<PageData> conversations = new List<PageData>();
    public UnityEvent postEvent; //Invoked on last page of Dialog
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, prefabs are meant to be a template to create new items of a type. You are trying to save data states.

Even though you cannot serialize the UnityEvent, you could serialize its content.

If you assign via inspector, you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEventBase.GetPersistentMethodName.html

But then you would not have problem of storage if you know from the start where it goes.

Second solution is when you assign the method to the UnityEvent, store it.

```
void AddListener (UnityAction ev)
{
     MethodInfo mi = ev.Method;
     // Use mi
     postEvent.AddListener(ev);
}
```

With the mi reference, you have the name of the method, its type, the object it belongs to and anything you need.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try PersistentMethodName since the whole point is to do it in the inspector. Can you explain why it does not work in a Scriptable object? Adding the actual UnityEvent to the Scriptable Object works fine, you can edit it in the inspector as intended. But all global values you try to access (for example `public int id = 12`) returns the default value.

Comment: Does it return default value or the value in the inspector? Are expecting to get the value given in the script? Try clicking Reset so inspector gets back to script values.